# Multiple AWS Accounts on Pig Script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-pig

I want to have access from a PIG Script from EMR to an s3 bucket from one account that I have aws_access_key and the aws_secret_key and I want to store the result files on another aws account. 
Is there any way that I can do this? I've already tried s3n path with credentials but it doesn't work.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this changing the PigStorage function , storing in hdfs the results,  and on the cleanUpWithSucess method invoke a method that uploads the hdfs files to s3 with credentials. In this way I can pass the credentials to the PigStorageFunction when it is used to store, of course I also changed the constructor of the PigStorage to receive these arguments.